# Bigquery could not get default credentials

Tags: php, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication, google-authenticator

I'm trying to setup Google Bigquery with Firebase and am having some issues. I have `gcloud` installed on my machine (MacOS Sierra) and have google cloud installed via composer on my project.

The following code on my project:

```
# Includes the autoloader for libraries installed with composer
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

# Imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;

# Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
$projectId = 'hidden here only';

# Instantiates a client
$bigquery = new BigQueryClient([
    'projectId' => $projectId
]);

# The name for the new dataset
$datasetName = 'test_dataset';

# Creates the new dataset
$dataset = $bigquery->createDataset($datasetName);

echo 'Dataset ' . $dataset->id() . ' created.';
```

All I'm trying to do is just create a dataset within bigquery via the library but I'm not able to due to the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Cloud\Exception\ServiceException: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/projects/work/bigquery-tests/vendor/google/cloud/src/RequestWrapper.php on line 219
```

I've tried running `gcloud beta auth applications-default login` as the example code says to do but after logging in on the browser, the error is still present. Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were very close, just you need to setup the service account default credentials see lines with `putenv` and `useApplicationDefaultCredentials()`. This is a working code I have using the library https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client You need to obtain your service account key file from the console: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/cloud": "^0.13.0",
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0"
    }
}
```

**php file**

```
# Imports the Google Cloud client library
use Google\Cloud\BigQuery\BigQueryClient;
use Google\Cloud\ServiceBuilder;

$query="SELECT repository_url, 
       repository_has_downloads 
FROM   [publicdata:samples.github_timeline]
LIMIT  10";
$client = new Google_Client();
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='.dirname(__FILE__) . '/.ssh/dummyname-7f0004z148e1.json');//this can be created with other ENV mode server side
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

$builder = new ServiceBuilder([
                'projectId' => 'edited',
        ]);

        $bigQuery = $builder->bigQuery();

        $job = $bigQuery->runQueryAsJob($query);
        $info=$job->info();
//      print_r($info);
//      exit;
        $queryResults = $job->queryResults();

        /*$queryResults = $bigQuery->runQuery(
            $query,
            ['useLegacySql' => true]);*/

        if ($queryResults->isComplete()) 
        {
            $i = 0;
            $rows = $queryResults->rows();

            foreach ($rows as $row) 
            {
                $i++;

                $result[$i] = $row;
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            throw new Exception('The query failed to complete');
        }

        print_r($result);
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the `google/apiclient` dependency to do that. The `putenv` call should be sufficient to instantiate `ServiceBuilder`.

Comment: @Pentium10 How do I download the key file? I have permission to view the keys but I don't see a download button.

Comment: @JoeScotto please see the following link for a guide on how to download your keyfile:

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/v0.20.1/guides/authentication

Comment: @davids I think I got it working, I'm no longer getting a connection error. I now have an access denied error which I think at least means I'm connected.